# Add data-cy to element in extJs

Tags: unit-testing, extjs, frontend, cypress, uniqueidentifier

I'm searching to add a data-cy to my elements in my ExtJs, but seems that nothing works. The piece where I want to add it is the following one:

```
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'values',
                        name: 'value_x',
                        hideTrigger: true,
                    }
```

The whole code works, then the problem is that it cannot recognise it. I've already tried these codes, but any of them works:

```
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(cmp) {
            cmp.getEl().set({
                "data-intro": 'some text',
                "data-step": 1
            });
        }
    }
```

```
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'div',
        'data-step': '1'
    }
```

I substitute data-step and data-intro with my data-cy, but nothing.
The problem is that it doesn't return any error, but the data-cy (I've tried also with data-attribute and data-intro) is not put into the DOM when I open the localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I solved the problem using simply

```
autoEl: {
        'data-cy': ’1'
    }
```

Without specifying the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are not telling us which Version you are using.
From the example I take it that it is the 'CLASSIC' framework and I guess the latest version.

This works in my fiddle:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.Container', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'custom',
    
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'div',
        'data-step': '1',
        'data-cy': 2
    }
});
```

If you do not add the tag, it will automatically use `div`, so that your answer works too. But for fun exchange `div` for `blockquote` and you will see how it works in more detail.

In 'MODERN' you can use:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.Custom', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'custom',
    
    template: [{
        reference: 'bodyElement',
        tag: 'blockqoute',
        cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'body-el',
        uiCls: 'body-el',
        'data-cy': 1
    }],
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way of doing this. You could also extend this with any other value.

```
{
     xtype: 'button',
     text: 'Login',
     handler: 'doLogin',
     testId: 'loginBtn',
}
```

and then override the Ext.Component.js

````
Ext.define('Portal.overrides.Component', {
    override: 'Ext.Component',

    /**
     * convert testId into data-cy
     */
    onRender() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        const { el } = this;
        const testId = this.testId || this.itemId || '';
        if (el && el.dom && !Ext.isEmpty(testId) && Ext.isEmpty(this.inputAttrTpl)) {
            const attId = this.cyAtt || 'data-cy';
            el.dom.setAttribute(attId, testId);
        }
    },
});
```

Got that code from here: [Github][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/rjben/Coworkee/blob/master/client/overrides/Component.js
````